# how to update max_input_vars on ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache

There are no change in phpinfo result but already updated on /etc/php/8.1/php.ini

php.ini

max_input_vars = 10000

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; https://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M

phpinfo result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0VaA.png)

Comment: PHP on ubuntu usually have two different php.ini. One for CLI /etc/php/x.x/cli/php.ini and another for php-fpm or apache, depending on which you use. If you're using php-fpm, you need to change the one in that folder and then restart the php-fpm service. If you're using apache and mod_php (usually the default), then you need to change that one and then restart apache.

Comment: **Hint**: phpinfo will show you what ini file(s) has been used. Also, don't forget to restart your server (apache or whatever) to apply your changes.